# How to Detect File Rename / Move in Windows

Tags: java, python, file, rename, move

I'm trying to detect when a file is being moved or renamed in windows and I want to then use that change to update a database.

When I say file move: I mean moving from one directory to another from ".../A/foo.txt" to ".../B/foo.txt".
When I say file rename: I mean renaming but staying in the same directory ".../A/foo.txt" to ".../A/bar.txt"

I know that linux and most people treat them as the same thing, and for my purposes they are the same thing. I just want to know the actual file path after and be able to match it to the original file path even in circumstances where there is a batch move.

I am using python for the parent program, but I am willing to use any coding language though it preferably is Java/Python/some form of C.

Comment: Just to clarify, I can use any version of Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use java 7, you can simply use `WatchService` and `WatchKey`. This is a observer to watch a directory and each time something is changed, created or deleted you can do an action/file handling.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the watchdog python module https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog

It can handle these situations as well as other filesystem events

Answer (score 0):

In Java (WatchService and WatchKey) - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

In Python (Watchdog) - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog